# How to get hold of the string inside a specific font color (to add something to the text, NOT changing the color) Find.Text empty

Tags: vba, ms-word

this is my first post in this forum and I am also doing my first steps in word VBA, so please be patient with a poor latin teacher.
This is what I want to do:

In my active document I select a text with several words (or parts of words) formatted red. These words are the correct solutions for a CLOZE question (fill in the blank). Here is an example (red = bold):

Galli ad oppidum **venerunt**.
Caesar Q. Pedium legatum in Galliam **misit**.

This should become:

1. Romani ad oppidum (veniunt) {1:SHORTANSWER:=venerunt}.
2. Caesar Q. Pedium legatum in Galliam (mittit) {1:SHORTANSWER:=misit}.

So what I have to do is:

1. Find all  red text snippets,
2. Foreach found red textsnippet insertBefore "{1:SHORTANSWER:=}" and insertAfter "}".

I tried to work with Selection.Find.Font.Color = wdColorRed, but then, how do I get hold of each 'instance' and how do I loop through it? The Find-Object has a property Text, but that is always empty :-(

Can you help me please?

Kind regards
Thomasina

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
    .Format = True
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    .InsertBefore "{1:SHORTANSWER:="
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Text = "}"
    .Font.ColorIndex = wdAuto
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It's not apparent where '(veniunt)' and '(mittit)' are supposed to come from, however.

It's also not clear whether the F/R is supposed to insert the paragraph breaks.

Comment: You made not only my day, you made weeks of my life and those of my colleagues! It works like a charme, and I will no go through every line and read the docs in order to understand what happens.
veniunt (they come) and mittit (he sends) are part of the question. They are in present tense and the students shall build the appropriate form in past perfect.
The paragraph breaks are set manually in the text, so we can leave them alone.
Thanks a lot, Thomasina